# Keras fit not training model weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to fit a simple histogram model with custom weights and no input. It should fit a histogram for the data generated by:

```py
train_data = [max(0,int(np.round(np.random.randn()*2+5))) for i in range(1000)]
```

The model is defined by

```py
d = 15
class hist_model(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(hist_model,self).__init__()
        self._theta = self.add_weight(shape=[1,d],initializer='zero',trainable=True)
        
    
    def call(self,x):
        return self._theta
```

The problem I have is that training using `model.fit` doesn't work: The model weights don't change at all during training. I tried:

```py
model = hist_model()
model.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-2),
                loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy")
history = model.fit(train_data,train_data,verbose=2,batch_size=1,epochs=10)
model.summary()
```

Which returns:

```
Epoch 1/3
1000/1000 - 1s - loss: 2.7080
Epoch 2/3
1000/1000 - 1s - loss: 2.7080
Epoch 3/3
1000/1000 - 1s - loss: 2.7080
Model: "hist_model_17"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
Total params: 15
Trainable params: 15
Non-trainable params: 0
________________________
```

I tried writing a custom training loop for the same model, it worked well. This is the code for the custom training:

```py
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-3)
loss_fn = keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
for epoch in range(3):
    running_loss = 0
    for data in train_data:
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            loss_value = loss_fn(data,model(data))
            running_loss += loss_value.numpy()
            grad = tape.gradient(loss_value,model.trainable_weights)
            optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grad, model.trainable_weights))
    print(f'Epoch {epoch} loss: {loss_value}')
```

I still don't understand why the fit method doesn't work. What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your custom loop that works?

Comment: @AloneTogether Added now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the two methods is probably the loss function. Try running:

```
model.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-2),
                loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True))
```

since the `from_logits` parameter is set to `False` by default. Meaning it is expected that the output of your model already encodes a probability distribution. Notice the loss differences now with `from_logits=True`:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

d = 15
class hist_model(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(hist_model,self).__init__()
        self._theta = self.add_weight(shape=[1,d],initializer='zero',trainable=True)       
    
    def call(self,x):
        return self._theta

train_data = [max(0,int(np.round(np.random.randn()*2+5))) for i in range(15)]

model = hist_model()
model.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-2),
                loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True))

history = model.fit(train_data, train_data,verbose=2,batch_size=1,epochs=10)
```

```
Epoch 1/10
15/15 - 0s - loss: 2.7021 - 247ms/epoch - 16ms/step
Epoch 2/10
15/15 - 0s - loss: 2.6812 - 14ms/epoch - 915us/step
Epoch 3/10
15/15 - 0s - loss: 2.6607 - 15ms/epoch - 1ms/step
Epoch 4/10
15/15 - 0s - loss: 2.6406 - 14ms/epoch - 955us/step
Epoch 5/10
15/15 - 0s - loss: 2.6209 - 19ms/epoch - 1ms/step
Epoch 6/10
15/15 - 0s - loss: 2.6017 - 18ms/epoch - 1ms/step
Epoch 7/10
15/15 - 0s - loss: 2.5829 - 15ms/epoch - 999us/step
Epoch 8/10
15/15 - 0s - loss: 2.5645 - 15ms/epoch - 1ms/step
Epoch 9/10
15/15 - 0s - loss: 2.5464 - 27ms/epoch - 2ms/step
Epoch 10/10
15/15 - 0s - loss: 2.5288 - 20ms/epoch - 1ms/step
```

I think the reduction method used might also have an influence. Check the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy) for more details.